# Unable to Find MUI Dropdown Option in React Testing Library Test

Tags: typescript, material-ui, react-testing-library

I'm trying to write a test for a React component that renders a dropdown menu using Material-UI (MUI) components. However, I'm encountering an issue where I'm unable to find an element with the data-testid "dropdown-option0". I've provided my code below for reference.

```
import MenuItem from "@mui/material/MenuItem";
import FormControl from "@mui/material/FormControl";
import Select, { SelectChangeEvent } from "@mui/material/Select";
import { useState } from "react";
import { dropdownMenuData } from "./data";

function DropdownMenu() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState("");
  const handleChange = (event: SelectChangeEvent) => {
    console.log(event.target.value as string);
    setValue(event.target.value as string);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <Select
          value={value}
          onChange={handleChange}
          data-testid="dropdown-menu"
        >
          {dropdownMenuData.option.Options.map((option, index) => (
            <MenuItem
              key={index}
              value={index}
              data-testid={`dropdown-option${index}`}
            >
              {Object.values(option)}
            </MenuItem>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </>
  );
}
```

I'm using the React Testing Library to write my test, and the test code looks like this:

```
import { render, fireEvent, screen, waitFor } from "@testing-library/react";
import DropdownMenu from "./dropdown";

test("renders dropdown with options and selects an option", async () => {
  render(<DropdownMenu />);

  await waitFor(() => {
    const dropdown = screen.getByTestId("dropdown-menu");
    fireEvent.click(dropdown);

    const selectOption = screen.getByTestId("dropdown-option0");
    fireEvent.click(selectOption);
  });
});
```

However, when I run the test, I'm getting the following error:

```
"renders dropdown with options and selects an option"
```

```
Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="dropdown-option0"]
```

I've considered that this might be due to a timing issue or a mismatch in the component hierarchy between the actual render and the test environment, but I'm not sure how to proceed to fix it. Can someone help me understand what might be causing this issue and how to resolve it? Are there any best practices I should follow when testing Material-UI components with React Testing Library?

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

#### What I Tried and Expected:

I've written a test using React Testing Library for a dropdown component that utilizes Material-UI components. I expected the test to render the dropdown and successfully select an option.

#### Actual Result:

The test is failing with an error message: "Unable to find an element by: [data-testid="dropdown-option0"]". Despite the dropdown being rendered and opened, the test seems unable to locate the specific option element by its data-testid.